# align all the text boxes in same vertical position

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

How can I make align all the textboxes align in same vertical position? 
My textboxes are starting just after the label is completed. The textboxes are following the width of the label. 
*It is also to be noted that all the labels are left justified*. *Can I do this without using tables, just only html and css?*

Code ::

```
<div style="width: 100%; font-family: Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;">

                <div style="text-align: left; width: 100%; font-size: 13px;margin-bottom:5px;">
                    <b>Previous Password:</b>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_prev_pwd" runat="server"  />
                </div>
                <div style="text-align: left; width: 100%; font-size: 13px;margin-bottom:5px;">
                    <b>New Password:</b>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_new_pwd" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div style="text-align: left; width: 100%; font-size: 13px;margin-bottom:5px;">
                    <b>Retype Password:</b>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_re_pwd" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Try either tables or flex-boxes

Comment: Can I do this without using table?

Comment: Using div and css you can do.

Comment: Yes. check out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: use display: table & display:table-row & display: table-cell

Comment: @EmadEmami can you provide the sample code block?

Comment: yes, it's in my answer! just run code snippet to see

Comment: yes you can do that only using css and html, can i change that asp into input tags to answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add to `b` tag CSS styles:

```
b{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

I recommend change `<b>` tag on `<label>`, add a class name, and then style it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code:

```css
.fields{display:table}
.fields-row{display: table-row;}
.fields-row b{display: table-cell}
```

```html
<div class="fields">

                <div class="fields-row">
                    <b>Previous Password:</b>
                    <input type=text />
                </div>
                <div class="fields-row">
                    <b>New Password:</b>
                    <input type=text />
                </div>
                <div class="fields-row">
                    <b>Retype Password:</b>
                    <input type=text />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping each line in a separate div that specifies the width and use the CSS property `float`, `text-align` and `align`

```html
<div style="max-width: 50%; align: center">
  <div style="max-width: 50%; text-align: center; float: left">Field #1</div>
  <div style="max-width: 50%; text-align: center; float: right">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div style="max-width: 50%; align: center">
  <div style="max-width: 50%; text-align: center; float: left">Field #2 Blah</div>
  <div style="max-width: 50%; text-align: center; float: right">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div style="max-width: 50%; align: center">
  <div style="max-width: 50%; text-align: center; float: left">Here's field #3</div>
  <div style="max-width: 50%; text-align: center; float: right">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Whitcik response is pretty accurate, I would prefeer using relative width:

```
b{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 75%;
  min-Width: 20%;
}
```

This way, you can test in different widths keeping stable the aspect ratio (mobile devices). This is just ANOTHER solution. Whitcik is completely right with his response ;)